# Why is MySQL sometimes failing to connect to AWS RDS Aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm getting a bizarre behavior on an EC2 instance connecting to an AWS RDS cluster that I can't explain. With the exact same connection string, it works about 20% of the time. I at first thought it had to do with a Drupal installation issue, but I stepped back and tried directly connecting from the command line, and I'm getting the same thing. Here are some examples of the outcome:

```
[root@xxx]# mysql -u admin -h cluster-name-removed.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'10.1.18.15'
[root@xxx]# mysql -u admin -h cluster-name-removed.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'10.1.19.253'
[root@xxx]# mysql -u admin -h cluster-name-removed.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'10.1.18.15'
[root@xxx]# mysql -u admin -h cluster-name-removed.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'10.1.18.15' 
[root@xxx]# ^C
[root@xxx]# mysql -u admin -h cluster-name-removed.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p
Enter password:
SUCCESS.
```

This also is similar to what I was seeing from Drupal: about a quarter of the time the pages loaded.

Those IP addresses are - I think private IP addresses that I've never seen in our network, so I don't know where they are coming from.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying that IP address is not the private IP address of the EC2 instance? Is this an RDS Aurora cluster?

Comment: Right, that is not the private IP address of either the EC2 instance nor the Database. Yes, it is a cluster

Comment: More info: it seems like a problem with either the db cluster or the network between the instances and the db cluster. I don't see the problem when connecting to other clusters, but I do see it when connecting to the cluster from other instances.

Comment: Could it be that not all the cluster instances have that MySQL user configured on them?

Comment: I'm not sure how to actually check each instance inside the cluster. Is that possible? I may have found the answer from this troubleshooting guide: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-connection-issues/ - under the localhost and % section. I'm not sure if it makes sense, but I moved back to just the one main db user, and I haven't seen the problem again so far. Thanks your suggestions!

Comment: Each instance in the cluster has its own endpoint for connecting directly to that instance. You could go through each one to test that.

Comment: This looks to me more like your DB user is not set up properly. It's probably set in the way that it allows only access from certain IP address. You should try with `SHOW GRANTS` command to see if that user  is set for specific IP address (it will look like 'admin'@'some-ip-address') if it has 'admin'@'%' then it's set up for access from any IP

Answer (score 0):

This isn't entirely an answer, but I've found two things that work. One might be a red herring.

1. If I use a connection string that contains the password in it - i.e. -pThePasswordHere - it would complain about a special character in the password, specifically a close parenthesis. When I connect normally, it would tell me Access Denied, but not complain about the parenthesis. Changing the password to not contain special characters made it work.
2. Creating a new user also made it work.

I didn't test making a new user with the old password with a close parenthesis though so can't say 100% which is the answer.